# window.location.hash doesn't "see" URLs containing #:~:text=

Tags: javascript, url

When Google features a block of a text at the top of its results page, it will link to the site and add a hash with some text in it.

For example, this is the URL from the top result if I search for "daily management system":

[https://tervene.com/blog/daily-management-system-dms/#:~:text=A%20Daily%20Management%20System%2C%20commonly,as%20planned%20and%20continuously%20improves](https://tervene.com/blog/daily-management-system-dms/#:%7E:text=A%20Daily%20Management%20System%2C%20commonly,as%20planned%20and%20continuously%20improves).

If I run "window.location.hash" in the JS console on that page, I get an empty strong.  What gives?

Comment: Chrome processes that itself, using it to highlight the text. It's removed before sending the URL to the page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, I found that this particular hash is called a Text Fragment and Chrome strips it out of window.location.

However, it's still possible to get the "true" URL with this:

```
performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].name
```